# Setting colors of an entire Excel range to array of colors

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have an Excel.Range with 10 cells and I want to change its color by using a 0 based 2d array with 10 elements of Excel.XlRgbColor.

```
object[,] colorsTest = new object[10, 1]
    {
        { Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbAliceBlue, Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbAliceBlue},
        { Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbAliceBlue, Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbAliceBlue}...
        (8 more)
    };

Excel.Range range = activeSheet.Range[activeSheet.Cells[1, 1], activeSheet.Cells[10, 1]];
```

But now when I try to set

```
range.Interior.Color = colorsTest;
```

I get a Type mistmatch error for some reason. When I try to set the range's value with the array, everything works like intended - I get the indexes of my colors pasted into the cells as values, like expected.

Any idea what could be causing this? I think the type is what it should be.

I have about 5000 rows this has to apply to so looping through them separately results in tragic performance.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea but unfortunately it's not possible to set different color for each cell in a range they way you wanted to do that. I'm actually surprised you didn't get an error.

I also agree with "tragic performance" I guess we're talking about minutes here.
I see just a few options here

- **Copy format** - if the colors are stable and you will always apply the same or just a few variation of them. I'd prepare the colored cells somewhere, like in range AA1:AA10 and when you want to apply the colors I'd just copy & paste format to your range
- **[OpenXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx)** - I believe it would be a way faster than accessing cells one by one but I assume you will code it for at least one day. I don't have too much experience with OpenXML SDK but from what I have done I can tell you it's pretty verbose

Comment: I am getting a Type mismatch error, I just forgot about one of the attributes I applied.